# Delete vertices in a geometry in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I can't figure out how can I delete a vertex after I've created a geometry (polygon or line) in the map editor of Google Earth Engine. It is possible to create a new one by clicking in the middle point between vertices and It is also possible to delete the entire geometry (by clicking on it and pressing delete), but is it possible to delete a vertex using just the map editor?